# Loading all env variables with processbuilder

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder

I want to load the variables I have defined in the .bashrc file prior to the execution of a script from a java code. The script is executed via the ProcessBuilder. On the web, I see that the command array should be started with `bash -c` as below:

```
String[] cmdline = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "python", "/home/mahmood/temp.py"};
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdline);
pb.command(cmdline);
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
final Process p = pb.start();
int exitCode = p.waitFor();
if (exitCode != 0) {
   throw new IOException("... python failed :( \n");
}
```

Indeed the waitFor never returns! If I drop the `bash -c`, then the `exitCode` will be non-zero since the variables have not been loaded.

Please note that there is not a single variable in the .bashrc. Can I fix the problem with ProcessBuilder or there is a better option for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Bash` has to be **invoked as an interactive shell** to [read and execute commands from `~/.bashrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files). When running `bash -c command` you're executing `command` in a non-interactive shell. To run interactively (and read `.bashrc`), just add `-i`:

```
String[] cmdline = {"/bin/bash", "-ic", "python /home/mahmood/temp.py"};
```

Also, note that the command string (`python /path/to/file`) has to be specified as a **single word** (notice single quotes when invoked from shell):

```
bash -ic 'python /home/mahmood/temp.py'
```

or otherwise, `bash` will execute `python` (the first word) *interactively* (not running the script) -- and that's the reason your `waitFor` never returns.

---

Since running an interactive shell just to load some environment variables from `.bashrc` might be an overkill, you could **extract the variables of interest in a separate file**, for example:

```
export var1=val1
export var2='val 2'
...
```

and then **source** that file just **before running** your `python` script:

```
String[] cmdline = {"/bin/bash", "-c", ". /path/to/envfile; python /home/mahmood/temp.py"};
```

Comment: Although the first method ran the script, I see that after the execution of `pb.start()` these lines are printed on the output window `bash: cannot set terminal process group (1615): Inappropriate ioctl for device` and `bash: no job control in this shell`

Comment: Also, what is the difference between using `-ic` and `"-c". "source ~/.bashrc; python..."`?

Comment: You're seeing that message because you're running Bash as [interactive shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shells), but with no terminal attached (because you run it from Java). Interactive shell is a little bit "heavier" to run (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior)), that's why the second method might be preferred. In the second method, Bash is run in non-interactive mode, but before executing Python script, we first source our environment variables (`-ic` is just as short way of writing `-i -c`).

Comment: The difference between `-ic` and `-c 'source ~/.bashrc; python ...'` (besides the fact you're not running interactive shell with second expression) is that your `.bashrc` will probably prematurely exit *if not* run in an interactive shell -- check the beginning of your `.bashrc` and look for something like: `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. If you modify your `.bashrc` not to exit when sourced in non-interactive shell, for example just to hold env vars, then you're approaching the second method from the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually I learned many things about shell from this Q&A which I have't noticed til now!

Answer (score 1):

One another approach is to add the environment variables manually as part of `ProcessBuilder` environment.

For example, assuming we have stored the required environment variables inside a string array `envVars`, following snippet will add the environment variables as part of `ProcessBuilder`'s environment:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("python", "temp.py"));
pb.directory(new File("/home/mahmood/"));
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
Map<String, String> envToReproduce = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(int x=0;x<envVars.length;x++){
    System.out.println(envVars[x]);
    String[] tempEnv = envVars[x].split("=");
    if(tempEnv.length>1){                           
        String envVal = tempEnv[1].replaceAll("'","");
        envToReproduce.put(tempEnv[0], envVal);
        env.put(tempEnv[0], envVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that the `pb.environment()` returns something different than my bashrc. I am debugging with Netbeans, so I think when Netbeans executes, it doesn't read the bashrc and therefore user defined variables are ignored. That means, with Netbeans it is much harder than what I thought! To test the proposed idea, I have to run and debug from the terminal. Thanks.